# Cascading input control based on multiple parameter---Jasper Server

Tags: jasperserver, cascading

I would be thankful if anybody help me in this regard.

I have three parameters as below on jaspersoft server. and I want to build cascading input control as follows.

`Parameter1` is a list with  multiple select.
`parameter2` is also a list with multiple select.

but I want the `parameter3` should be filtered as what I have selected from the above two `parameter1` and `parameter2`.

I have tried the following third `parameter3` query but getting the result one `parameter1` or `parameter2`.

```
select id, name
where
$X{IN, samecolumn, parameter1}  AND $X{IN, samecolumn, parameter}
```

please I would be thankful for the response.

Comment: I think there is a sample in the jaspersoft server samples doing this. I cannot think of the name right now but I remember it being connected to some kind of demo dashboard.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i searched all the documentation but did not find anything related to this. still if it comes in your mind the samples, please write it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sample for this in the Jasper Reports demo data which comes with the server. This is not a part of the documentation as far as I know.

I searced for "cascade" in Jasper Reports Server and it is a report:

It is called `Cascading multi select topic`. Its description says: *Shows cascading input controls. Multi-select and single select queries*.

Comment: I have searched the whole server that is installed on PC but unfortunately havn't found anything what you mentioned above.

Comment: I would appreciate if attached the sample report or the related query.

Comment: Did you install the samples when installing the server? You can prevent the installation at the beginning somewhere. It would be worth to add all examples for later cases.

Comment: i reinstalled the server completely with all smaple reports but unfortunately  did nt find anything what you mentioned.

Comment: Do you use the Community or the Professional version?

Comment: There is a [small docs page with further information](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-user-guide/v62/adding-cascading-input-controls-report).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, it only works in jasper studio but not in jasper server.